# C++ Data Structures

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
// example about structures
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std; 

struct movies_t { 
    string title; 
    int year; 
} mine, yours; 

void printmovie (movies_t movie); 

int main () 
{ 
 string mystr; 
 mine.title = "2001 A Space Odyssey"; 
 mine.year = 1968; 
 cout << "Enter title: "; 
 getline (cin,yours.title); 
 cout << "Enter year: "; 
 getline (cin,mystr); 
 stringstream(mystr) >> yours.year; 
 cout << "My favorite movie is:\n "; 
 printmovie (mine); 
 cout << "And yours is:\n "; 
 printmovie (yours); 
 return 0; 
} 

void printmovie (movies_t movie) 
{ 
 cout << movie.title; 
 cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n"; 
}
```

What I don't understand is where the extra "movie" comes from in the two void printmovie function arguments. At first I thought it was supposed to be a function argument, but there isn't a comma separating it and "movies_t". Could you also explain how the printmovie function interacts with the movies_t data structure?

Answer (score 2):

`printmovie` takes only one argument.

`movies_t` is the **type** of the argument.
`movie` is the **argument name**.

The important thing to remember is that C++ is a statically typed language, and every variable has a type associated with it (for example: `int`, `char`, or a user defined type such as `movie_t`). This isn't Python.

Comment: Python is strongly typed too. What it's not, is statically typed.

Comment: Thanks. (note to self: do not attempt to talk about type systems at 22:00).

Comment: @McLovin: Do they make more sense at 0200?

Comment: Ok so what I'm understanding now is that once you define a function that has an instance of a data structure as its argument, you can use any of the struct's objects(i.e. mine or yours) as an argument in the calling of the function to yield different results? Why can't we just use the name of the data structure as the function argument?

Comment: @user3580073: How would that work if you wanted two arguments of the same type to the function? Or if you wanted to declare another object of the same type in the function body?

Answer (score 1):

`printmovie()` takes one argument. Its name is `movie` and its type is `movies_t`.

Answer (score 1):

It is an argument. For example, you give an int parameter to a function like,

```
void function(int name);
```

In the same way, struct is a user-defined data type, hence anything that uses the movies_t keyword becomes a variable of struct type with  the format defined under movie_t with a string called movies title and an int called year. So, effectively, that is what you are saying in the function header that the variable movie is a struct of the format defined in movie_t.